# Updating password mysqli in PHP if a new one is entered

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm a little new to PHP and mysqli and don't think I'm going around this the right way; maybe I need to check if it's the same, and if not update the password? I'm not sure how to do this though.

At the moment on the user edit form I'm not passing the current password value, but I can pass it and it will pass as md5 format.

PHP

```
    // user information
    $getID = $_POST['id']; // id
    $name = $_POST['name']; // name
    $username = $_POST['username']; // username
    $email = $_POST['email']; // email
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // phone
    $password = md5($_POST['password']); // password

    if($password == ''){
        // the query
        $query = "UPDATE users SET
                    name = ?,
                    username = ?,
                    email = ?,
                    phone = ?
                 WHERE id = ?
                ";
    } else {
        // the query
        $query = "UPDATE users SET
                    name = ?,
                    username = ?,
                    email = ?,
                    phone = ?,
                    password =?
                 WHERE id = ?
                ";
    }

    /* Prepare statement */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    if($stmt === false) {
      trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if($password == ''){
        /* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
        $stmt->bind_param(
            'ssss',
            $name,$username,$email,$getID
        );
    } else {
        /* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
        $stmt->bind_param(
            'sssss',
            $name,$username,$email,$password,$getID
        );
    }
```

Comment: What you want? can you state it correctly?

Comment: I have a user edit form to edit a user, if the user enters a new password on the form for it to also update the password field with a new password but if nothing entered to use one already set for the user in the database.

Comment: *"Updating password mysqli php if new one is entered"* - that tells me you want to update their password if the one they are using presently, is different than the one in db; not a good idea. You should be resetting a new one and using `password_hash()`.

Comment: Ok, is that difficult to update using password_hash? sorry im really new to this.

Comment: Check at coalesce function, it will help you

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5? other?

Comment: someone gave you an answer below; I'm out of the loop, ask them.

Comment: Yea im re-doing it using password_hash and password_verify anyway

Comment: great. so now see the answer below

Comment: Im trying the solution below now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did one mistake in your code.do not use MD5 before checking blank password . MD5 also encrypt blank value so $password == '' condition always wrong.

```
  // user information
        $getID = $_POST['id']; // id
        $name = $_POST['name']; // name
        $username = $_POST['username']; // username
        $email = $_POST['email']; // email
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; // phone

    /// do not use md5 here so condition get false always
        $password = $_POST['password']; // password

        if($password == ''){
            // the query
            $query = "UPDATE users SET
                        name = ?,
                        username = ?,
                        email = ?,
                        phone = ?
                     WHERE id = ?
                    ";
        } else {
            // the query
            $query = "UPDATE users SET
                        name = ?,
                        username = ?,
                        email = ?,
                        phone = ?,
                        password =?
                     WHERE id = ?
                    ";
        }

        /* Prepare statement */
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        if($stmt === false) {
          trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        if($password == ''){
            /* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'ssss',
                $name,$username,$email,$getID
            );
        } else {

$password = md5($password);
            /* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'sssss',
                $name,$username,$email,$password,$getID
            );
        }
```

Comment: I tried the above and got the following: <br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>/home/ambnews/public_html/invoice/response.php</b> on line <b>1119</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [<a href='mysqli-stmt.bind-param'>mysqli-stmt.bind-param</a>]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in <b>/home/ambnews/public_html/invoice/response.php</b> on line <b>1120</b>

Comment: ok check now I did some changes in code.It gives error because use function in bind_param.

Comment: yes one above, on the user edit page i just need to be able ot update details which all works but password is the one im stuck on. I only want to update the password if a new password is set in the password input.

Comment: Yep just getting: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [<a href='mysqli-stmt.bind-param'>mysqli-stmt.bind-param</a>]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in <b>/home/ambnews/public_html/invoice/response.php</b> on line <b>1114</b><br />

Comment: All done and working, was missing phone from bind thanks for your help